# Simple $Z^{*}$ algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

What is  an example of a simple $C^{*}$ algebra which all elements  are (two  sided or equivalently one  sided) zero divisor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take compact operators on a non-separable Hilbert space. For each such an operator you'll find a rank-one projection with range in the kernel of that operator.

<s>I guess that by some Löwenheim–Skolem-type argument, this gives you a separable example too.</s> (As observed by Andreas Thom.)

Comment: There is no separable example. If $(a_n)_n$ is a dense sequence, then $\sum_n a_n^*a_n/(2^n \|a_n\|^2)$ is a non-zero divisor.

Comment: Oh yes, you are of course right. Thank you for spotting that.

Comment: @TomekKania  Thank you for  your  interesting  answer. Is this  example a  universal example in the  sense that: every  $Z^{*}$ algebra has a faithful or irreducible representation in some $\mathcal{K}(H)$? For example consider the  $C^{*}$  subalgebra  of  $B(H)$ generated  by all countable rank operators. According to your example it is again  a  $Z^{*}$ algebra. Can we embedd it in compact operators ? Can we represent it irreducibly in compact operators?

Comment: Each compact operator has countable spectrum. Consider your favourite C*-algebra that has elements with uncountable spectrum...

Comment: @TomekKania Is $K(H)$ as an abstract C* algebra isomorphic to the algebra of countable rank operators on non separable $H$?

Comment: No, not even as a Banach space.

Comment: @TomekKania  what is their  difference as two  Banach spaces?

Comment: The operators with separable range contain a copy of $\ell_\infty$ as a subspace. This is not the case for $K(H)$; dual of each separable subspace of $K(H)$ is separable.