# Obstructions for $C^\star$ algebras to contain a $Z^\star$ algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

As the  comment of  Andreas Thom indicated [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188344/simple-z-algebra), a  separable $C^\star$ algebra $A$ can  not contain a $Z^\star$ algebra.(A $Z^\star$ algebra is  a $C^\star$ algebra which all elements are zero  divisor). So  separability is  an obstruction for  $A$ to  **contain** a $Z^\star$  algebra.

Now  we  ask:

> Is it the only  obstruction? What type  of other obstructions can be introduced? In particular is it true that every non separable  algebra contains a $Z^\star$ algebra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ contains a $Z^*$ $C^*$-subalgebra iff it contains an uncountable family $\{ a_i \}$ of nonzero positive mutually orthogonal elements. If it has such a family, then $C^*(\{ a_i \})$ is $Z^*$. If it does not have such a family and $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra, then any maximal family $\{ a_n \}$ of n.p.m.o. elements in $B$ is at most countable and hence one can define $a := \sum_n 2^{-n}\| a_n \|^{-1} a_n \in B$, which is not a zero divisor. 
In particular, any $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor does not contain a $Z^*$ $C^*$-subalgebra.